# EditText values in RecyclerView change when items added to RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have a RecyclerView that contains a list of views with EditText fields in them.

I want to be able to change the value in the EditTexts and have that update my dataset. I seem to be accomplishing this but when I add a new item to the list, the values in the EditTexts get mixed up.

I cannot find why this is happening. Any thoughts?

**Main Activity**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myDataSet = ArrayList<Person>()
        myDataSet.add(Person("Tommy"))
        myDataSet.add(Person("John"))
        myDataSet.add(Person("Suzie"))
        myDataSet.add(Person("Leslie"))

        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        viewAdapter = PersonAdapter(myDataSet)

        recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvPersons).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)

            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = viewAdapter
        }

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.myButton)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            myDataSet.add(Person("new person"))
            myDataSet.forEach {person ->
                Log.i("my-tag", person.name)
            }
            rvPersons.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

**People Adapter**

```kotlin
class PersonAdapter(private val myDataSet: ArrayList<Person>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val editText: EditText = view.my_edittext
        var textView: TextView = view.my_textView
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_person, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.editText.setText(myDataSet[position].name)
        holder.editText.doAfterTextChanged { text ->
            if (!text.isNullOrBlank()) {
                myDataSet[position].name = text.toString()
            }
        }
        holder.textView.text = myDataSet[position].name
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = myDataSet.size
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For Recycler view Recycle issues :-
Add This

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: I am having a similar kind of issue can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73426528/6854117)?

Comment: How does these functions resolve the recycle issues? Please explain.

Answer (score 4):

Since old TextWachers are all left registered over onBindViewHolder calls, data is to be broken. Retain the reference to the TextWatcher in MyViewHolder and remove it first in onBindViewHolder().

```
class PersonAdapter(private val myDataSet: ArrayList<Person>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        val editText: EditText = view.my_edittext
        var textView: TextView = view.my_textView
        var watcher: TextWatcher? = null
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.editText.removeTextChangedListener(holder.watcher)

        holder.editText.setText(myDataSet[position].name)
        holder.watcher = holder.editText.doAfterTextChanged { text ->
            if (!text.isNullOrBlank()) {
                myDataSet[position].name = text.toString()
            }
        }
        holder.textView.text = myDataSet[position].name
    }
    
    :
}
```

Comment: I added this but It affescts all the rows when I change in one position edittext

Comment: I am having a similar kind of issue can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73426528/6854117)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `this.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding new text into editText.

Comment: I am having a similar kind of issue can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73426528/6854117)?